# Trouble populating UIPickerView with JSON array using Alamofire | Swift

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, uipickerview, uipickerviewcontroller

Essentially I have a textField that when pressed needs to open a UIPickerView with a selection that comes from JSON

I have separately worked on triggering a `UIPickerView` when selecting a `UItextField` and creating arrays from JSON in Swift but am having some trouble putting together.

For the `JSON` I am using Almofire simply because it simplifies the process
and the `UIPickerView` is written programmatically.

The JSON I am working with looks like this:

```
[{“model”:”model1”},{“model":"model2”},
{“model":"model3”},{“model":"model4”},{“model":"model5”},{“model":"model6”}]
```

The Almofire so far looks like this:

```
        let url = NSURL(string: "https://www.test.com/test/test")

        let data = NSData(contentsOf: url! as URL)
        var tmpValues = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data! as Data, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as! NSArray
        tmpValues = tmpValues as NSArray
        reloadInputViews()


        for candidate in tmpValues {
            if let cdict = candidate as? NSDictionary {

                //model is the column name in sql/json
                let model = cdict["model"]
                self.values.append(model! as AnyObject)


            }
        }
```

Triggering the `textField` to open a UIPickerView is done using the following code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController,UIPickerViewDataSource,UIPickerViewDelegate {


    @IBOutlet weak var TextField: UITextField!

    let model = ["model1","model2"]

    var pickerview = UIPickerView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        TextField.inputView = pickerview
        TextField.textAlignment = .center
        TextField.placeholder = "Select Your Model"

        pickerview.delegate = self
        pickerview.dataSource = self

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return Names.count
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return Names[row]
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        TextField.text = Names[row]
    }

}
```

How can I replace the hard-coded array with the JSON response?

Comment: Please don't use `NSURL`, `NSData`, `NSArray`, `NSDictionary`, `.mutableContainers` and `AnyObject` (for JSON data) in Swift. Use native types. And Swift variable names start with a lowercase letter. And **never** load data from a remote URL with synchronous `Data(contentsOf`. Don't do that.

Comment: I appreciate the pointers, why is bad to "load data from a remote URL with synchronous Data(contentsOf"

Comment: It blocks the thread. This causes bad user experience. Imagine the server is not available at the moment...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a lot of bad practices

- Don't use `NSURL`, `NSData`, `NSArray`, `NSDictionary` and `AnyObject` (for JSON data) in Swift. Use native types.
- Don't use `.mutableContainers`in Swift. The option is pointless. Omit the `options` parameter
- Swift variable names start with a lowercase letter.
- **Never ever** load data from a remote URL with synchronous `Data(contentsOf`. Use asynchronous `URLSession`

The most efficient solution is to decode the JSON with `Decodable`

Outside of the class declare the struct

```
struct Model : Decodable {
    let model : String
}
```

Declare the picker source as variable and in plural form

```
var models = [String]()
```

In `viewDidLoad` insert at the end

```
let url = URL(string: "https://www.test.com/test/test")!
let dataTask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, _, error in
    if let error = error { print(error); return }
    do { 
        let result = try JSONDecoder().decode([Model].self, from: data!)
        self.models = result.map{$0.model}
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
          self.pickerview.reloadAllComponents()
        }
    } catch { print(error) }
}
dataTask.resume()
```

Even with `JSONSerialization` (without the `Model` struct) it's pretty straightforward

```
let url = URL(string: "https://www.test.com/test/test")!
let dataTask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, _, error in
    if let error = error { print(error); return }
    do { 
        if let result = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!) as? [[String:String]]
            self.models = result.compactMap{$0["model"]}
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
              self.pickerview.reloadAllComponents()
            }
        }
    } catch { print(error) }
}
dataTask.resume()
```

The picker data source methods are

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return models.count
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    return models[row]
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    TextField.text = models[row]
}
```

`Alamofire` is overkill for a simple GET request

Comment: Oh, of course, I did not think of that. Are you familiar with how to implement the JSON response into the UIPickerView?

Comment: Declare `model` as `var`iable,  assign the result to `model`: `self.model = result.map{$0.model}` and reload the picker data in the DispatchQueue closure: `self.pickerview.reloadAllComponents()`

Comment: Can you please elaborate this in your answer? I have done something similar before but it did not work.

Comment: What if it was JSON Post request as well in Alamofire I could do:         `let parameters: Parameters = ["customer": "\(Customer)"]
        
        Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: parameters).responseString { response in
            print(response)
        }`       For example, I could it be done without it?

Comment: Your question doesn't mention a POST request. You could do it with `URLSession` as well. By the way `Alamofire` is heavily based on `URLSession`